# how to loop through children of the html string converted to html using react html parser in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I want to convert a html string to react element using [react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser).

*What I am trying to do?*

I have a string `"i am <some-tag text="hello"/> some text again"`

Now I have to extract the text attribute value `"hello"` and then form a string like below,

`"i am <span>hello</strong> some text again"`

so in order to do this I am using [react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser). (to note I am using it for the first time using the documentation) I have no idea where to start with, but I have tried something like below:

```
class Somecomponent extends React.PureComponent {
    get_text_attr = (el) => {
        if (el.type === 'some-tag') {
          const text_attr =`<span>${el.props.text}</span>`;
          return ReactHtmlParser(text_attr);
        }
        return '';
     };

     parse = (el) => {
         if (el && el.props.children && el.props.children.length) {
             let values = [];
             values.push(this.get_text_attr(el));
             return 
             values.concat([el.props.children].map(this.parse));
         }
         return this.get_text_attr(el) || el;
     };

    render = () => {
        const string = "i am <some-tag text="hello"/> some text again"
        const doc = ReactHtmlParser(string);
        const html_content = doc.map((el) => {
            return parse(el);
        }
        return (
            <div>{html_content}</div>
        );
     }
 }
```

The above code works fine if I provide string `"hello <some-tag text="sometext"/>"`, but does not work for `"hello <some-tag text="sometext"/> some more text"`.

The above string creates element like below:

```
[
    "hello",
    { $$typeof: Symbol(react.element),
      props: 
            children:[" some more text"],
            text: "sometext",
      type: some-tag,
]
```

How do I check if each element has children or not? As noticed from above snippet I have used

```
if (el && el.props.children && el.props.children.length)
```

This gives me the error `cannot read property children of undefined`. Could someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the fact the the `ReactHtmlParser` library can't interpret your custom self-closing tag. If you make add a closing tag instead, then it works.

```
class SomeComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  get_text_attr = (el) => {
      if (el.type === 'some-tag') {
        const text_attr =`<span>${el.props.text}</span>`;
        return ReactHtmlParser(text_attr);
      }
      return '';
   };

   parse = (el) => {
       return this.get_text_attr(el) || el;
   };

  render = () => {
      const string = 'i am <some-tag text="hello"></some-tag> some text again';
      const doc = ReactHtmlParser(string);
      const html_content = doc.map((el) => {
          return this.parse(el);
      })
      return (
          <div>{html_content}</div>
      );
   }
}
```

Note that you don't need the `if (el && el.props.children && el.props.children.length)` logic any more.

Comment: thanks a lot. but i get this string in self closing tag format.

Comment: how d'you mean? See this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-brook-elnoy - output is `i am hello some text again`

Comment: meaning i get this string in this format const string = 'i am <some-tag text="hello"/> some text again' from the server. i cannot change it i think.